# Trait d’union à l’imperatif avec infinitif

Tags: grammaire, usage, pronoms-personnels, impératif

Je ne comprends pas du tout pourquoi ces deux types de phrases sont différents.

La 1ère s'écrit avec un trait d’union « Regarde-le chanter »

Mais « Vas le voir » , « Viens me le dire si tu l’oses » s'écrivent sans.

Comment: Attention, le verbe « aller » à l'impératif s'écrit « va » sauf dans « vas-y ». La deuxième phrase s'écrit « va le voir ».

Answer (score 1):

Ces types de phrases sont différents car dans le cas des verbes *aller* et *venir*, le pronom personnel **se rapporte au verbe à l'infinitif qui suit** et non à celui à l'impératif:

> **Regarde-le** *chanter*
>
> **Vas** *le voir*
>
> **Viens** *me le dire*

Or, si le pronom personnel se rapporte à un infinitif placé après l'impératif, le trait d'union n'a pas lieu d'être ([source](http://mapage.noos.fr/mp2/le_trait_dunion.htm), [source](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frtraitunionimperatif.php)).

Dans la première phrase, en revanche, on voit que le pronom personnel se rapporte au verbe à l'impératif. La preuve : cette phrase serait correcte même sans le verbe à l'infinitif (même si son sens serait différent) : "*Regarde-le.*". Ce n'est pas le cas des autres phrases : "*Vas le*", "*Viens me le*"...

D'ailleurs, les exemples avec *aller* et *venir* pourrait très bien être formulés d'une façon qui obligerait les traits d'union, en remplaçant le verbe à l'infinitif par le pronom *y* :

> Vas le voir --> Vas-y
>
> Viens me le dire --> Viens-y (*forme beaucoup moins commune*)